# move images of star-sign in orbit like way in same activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make simple application of Zodiac signs where  I want  12 Zodiac signs to move in orbit like way in same activity and as user wants it swipe and select the sign which he wants i.e. Say If taurus is in Center nd it looks in the front ... and user want to select the Leo then it will swipe the finger the Leo will come in the center it will look in front

Image below is the top view of what I visualize and i hope its clear what I want... I read about the circular galleryView but that changes the activity and it will not show all the signs in one activity .. I want to achieve this in same activity ...

in easier way the main center image will be in front and other wills be dim behind the center image but when swipe it should be like in circular manner.....

[image]

The above image is top view of what i visualize

and the below image is what i want to achieve except that sun

[image]

Any help in android this way ?

Comment: I need same like this but in Square how can i do like this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7339818#7339818

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Carousel widget code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) may help you.